# reference on how to use libXml2 parsing

Tags: ios, libxml2

I am new to iphone apps development for apple. Can any one help me out with the understanding of the libxml2 parsing. I have the sample code provided by apple for the performance test of nsxml and libxml2 parsing. Is there any other sample available for objective c??..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer ::  

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799423/how-to-parse-the-xml-data-using-libxml-parsing

Answer (score 0):

Good sample code with good explanation: 
http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/libxml2_push_parsing

Answer (score 0):

Please visit these links may be provide some help to you

- [libxml2](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html)
- [libxml2](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.in/2008/10/getting-some-xml-love-with-libxml2.html)
- [nsxml](http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/)
- [nsxml](http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/08/parsing-xml-using-nsxmlparser.html)

Simple search of NSXML and libxml2 on google

Enjoy coding :)