# how to parse the xml data using libxml parsing

Tags: iphone, ios

This is a xml structure that I want to parse using libxml parsing.

[image]

[image]

How can i get the attribute value for "campaign" tag i.e **ID** and for the "image" tag i.e **url** and **size**.

If I use these values, i can extract the values of "code" tag and "name " tag.

```
static const char *kName_campaign = "campaign";
static const NSUInteger kLength_campaign = 9;
static const char *kName_code = "code";
static const NSUInteger kLength_code = 5;
static const char *kName_name = "name";
static const NSUInteger kLength_name = 5;
```

Then I get the code and name of current and upcoming campaign all together.
This is the code I use in the delegate which gets called when parsing is done.

```
static void endElementSAX(void *ctx, const xmlChar *localname, const xmlChar *prefix, const xmlChar *URI)
{    
    LibXMLParser *parser = (LibXMLParser *)ctx;
    
    if (parser.parsingASong == NO) return;
    
    if (prefix == NULL)
    {
        if (!strncmp((const char *)localname, kName_campaign, kLength_campaign)) 
        {
            [parser finishedCurrentSong];
            parser.parsingASong = NO;
        } 
        else if (!strncmp((const char *)localname, kName_code, kLength_code))
        {
            parser.currentSong.title = [parser currentString];
            NSLog(@"Code  :: %@",[parser currentString]);
        }
        else if (!strncmp((const char *)localname, kName_name, kLength_name)) 
        {
            parser.currentSong.category = [parser currentString];
            NSLog(@"Name :: %@",[parser currentString]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get the attributes values from start to bottom of **id** from "campaign" tag. **url** and **size** from "image" tag?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you not using `NSXMLParser`?

Comment: Cuz it is faster and memory friendly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static void startElementSAX(void *ctx, const xmlChar *localname, const xmlChar *prefix, const xmlChar *URI, int nb_namespaces, const xmlChar **namespaces, int nb_attributes,
int nb_defaulted, const xmlChar **attributes)
{

if (nb_attributes > 0)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* attributeDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)[NSNumber numberWithInt:nb_attributes]];
    for (int i=0; i<nb_attributes; i++)
    {
       NSString* key = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)attributes[0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
       NSString* val = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void*)attributes[3] length:(attributes[4] - attributes[3]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       attributes += 5;

       [attributeDict setValue:val forKey:key];
    }
 }
}
```

Try this..